# Upload multiply images with progress bar

Tags: javascript, image, upload

I tring to build a image upload website but I have problem when I try to add progress bar to the images(this problem happen only when I got more than 1 image).
If I upload more than 1 image it giving a progress bar only for one image.

```
var uuid,formData;
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    uuid = createUUID();
    formData = new FormData();
    var reader = new FileReader();
    /*
       Getting thumbnail of the uploaded image and adding a progress bar
       Here the problem with the progress bar it always create a div with
       same id: 'bar'+i (the i not changing and always stay the same)
    */
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.innerHTML = "<img src='" + this.result + "'/><div class='progress'><div id='bar" + i + "' class='progress-bar' role='progressbar' aria-valuenow='60' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' style='width: 0%;'>0%</div></div><a href='images/" + uuid + "' target='_blank'>Direct link</a>";
        ul.appendChild(li);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input[i]);
    // Add the image to the form
    formData.append('images[]', input[i], uuid);
    // HTTP request to upload each image
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open("POST", "upload.php", true);
    http.upload.onprogress = function (e) {
        if (e.lengthComputable) {
            var percentage = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
            document.getElementById('bar' + 1).style.width = percentage + "%";
        }
    };

    http.onerror = function () {
        alert('An error occurred while submitting the form. Maybe your file is too big');
    };
    http.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById("bar" + 1).className += " progress-bar-success";
    };
    http.send(formData);
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, does your last uploaded image only show a progress bar?

Comment: You need to maintain the XMLHttpRequest object for all the uploaded images. What is happening is that every time the loop runs, a new object replaces the old http variable and hence overwrites everything. So the http.upload.onprogress function would point to the elements of the last cycle of the loop. Hope you got what I mean.

Comment: @KapilKashyap Yeh I got what you mean and this the problem but I dont know how to fix it. I want that every image will get his progress bar and not upload everything at once.
btw it upload all the images but only the progress bar is for the last one.

Comment: Let me give it a shot as an answer as the method is too long for a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var uuid,formData,http,httpRequests = [];
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    uuid = createUUID();
    formData = new FormData();
    var reader = new FileReader();
    /*
       Getting thumbnail of the uploaded image and adding a progress bar
       Here the problem with the progress bar it always create a div with
       same id: 'bar'+i (the i not changing and always stay the same)
    */
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.innerHTML = "<img src='" + this.result + "'/><div class='progress'><div id='bar" + i + "' class='progress-bar' role='progressbar' aria-valuenow='60' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' style='width: 0%;'>0%</div></div><a href='images/" + uuid + "' target='_blank'>Direct link</a>";
        ul.appendChild(li);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input[i]);
    // Add the image to the form
    formData.append('images[]', input[i], uuid);

    // HTTP request to upload each image
    http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open("POST", "upload.php", true);
    http.upload.onprogress = function (e) {
        if (e.lengthComputable) {
            var percentage = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
            document.getElementById('bar' + 1).style.width = percentage + "%";
        }
    };

    http.onerror = function () {
        alert('An error occurred while submitting the form. Maybe your file is too big');
    };
    http.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById("bar" + 1).className += " progress-bar-success";
    };
    http.send(formData);

    // push the http request into the array
    httpRequests.push(http);
}
```

I haven't tried it out as I do not have the complete setup, but I hope this works :)

Let me know.

Comment: Nope, still same thing.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle so that I can work with the code.